# Globalization in blazor server project

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, globalization

I am trying to change the language of my website through language dropdown.
I am not able to find any example on globalization in blazor server project. However I have tried globalization in blazor web assemble and it worked fine for me.

Comment: [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=server)

Comment: https://www.forestbrook.net/docs/blazor/localization.html